# Slice buffer between byte 40 and 60

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

im new with Node.js, and i am learning to work with buffers, im doing the exercise on book Hands on Node, and im a bit confused with a exercise, cant find the solution, Bascily i must slice a buffer between the byte 40 and 60, my actual buffer has 100 bytes.

**I did this:**

```
var buffer = new Buffer(100);
var slice = buffer.slice(40,60);
console.log(slice);
```

**and i get this result:**

```
<Buffer 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b>
```

Ps: i did a for loop before and my buffer goes from 0 to 99;

Comment: What you expect see?

Comment: 0x28 == 40, 0x3b == 60, it's hex numbers

Comment: hmm, i know, should it not start on 3a for example?

Comment: @FilipeCosta, why it should start on `3a`, if you did `buffer.slice(start,end)`, where `start` is 40th byte, and `end` is 60th byte? So, as a result you got `slice` buffer of size 20 total bytes. If you wanted to get same size buffer but starting from `3a`, then you  should do `var slice = buffer.slice(59, 79)`.

Also, please note that [new Buffer is deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_size) , and you should use [Buffer.alloc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding) instead.